# Passing value from Javascript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
    // Geometry
    var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    var geometryOutput = `
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Latitude</strong>: ${lat}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Longitude</strong>: ${lng}</li>
      </ul>
      ;
    document.getElementById('geometry').innerHTML = geometryOutput;

  })
```

How can I pass the value `${lat}` to HTML? Is it possible?

Comment: It is already being passed to `${lat}` and `${lng}`, what else do you want?

Comment: You already have one answer in your code with innerHTML, although you are missing a closing back-tick.

Comment: Break your code like this `${ ' + lat + ' }`. Then you will be passing the variable into the code.

Comment: @Matt That is not necessary with ES6 string interpolation.

Comment: @AndyG Assuming he is using a browser that can use ES6 no?

Comment: @Matt Or has a polyfill of some kind, or is using a transpiler. Without further comment I would not assume that the interpolation is an issue.

Comment: @Matt If you are converting the template literal to a single quote string, sure. But then, why wrap the variable in an expression (`${}`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using pure javascript as shown below:

```
document.getElementById("get-lat").innerHTML=lat
```

And in your html, create an element with a unique id:

```
<span id="get-lat"></span>
```

Also, using jQuery in your javascript code, you can pass the value of `${lat}` to the html like this:

```
$('#get-lat').html(lat)
```

You have the choice between using pure javascript or a library like jQuery to accomplish this.

Comment: I think it preferable to answer with vanilla JavaScript first, as per the question, before mentioning jQuery.

Comment: can it display in input tag instead of span tag?

Comment: @JavaGuy add `<input type="text" id="get-lat" />` in your html. Then in your javascript code, add the following:

`document.getElementById('get-lat').value = lat`

Comment: @JavaGuy Were you able to do this?

Comment: @JavaGuy pleasure to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set class to the element you want to set value.
To set a value to you can use **append** or **html** means

Eg.

```
$('.divName').append(lat); or
$('.divName').html(lat);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try breaking your string before your variable. As @AndyG said it may be a different issue but this works in my browser:

```
var lat = 40;
var lng = 30;

var geometryOutput = '<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><strong>Latitude</strong>: '+lat+'</li><li class="list-group-item"><strong>Longitude</strong>: '+lng+'</li></ul>' 

document.getElementById('geometry').innerHTML = geometryOutput;
```

Just replace my numbers with your response data

Comment: This will output the dollar signs and curly brackets as plain text.

Comment: @agrm Good catch and took them out. Thanks